# Failed to load properties from junit spring

Tags: spring, maven, junit, filenotfoundexception, spring-test

I have got a project which works perfectly fine when run via java -jar command but if I run it via junit it fails not able to load property files which are loaded using spring context.Below is the directory structure

```
/src
 /main
  /java
  /resources
    /config
      /export
        export.properties
    context.xml
    startJob.bat
 test
  java
    execution
     Test1
```

context.xml contains below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:config/export/export.properties</value>
            </list>
         </property>
```

My test class is as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:context.xml"})
public class Test1 {

@Autowired
Export export;
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test2() {
        export.report();
```

when I run the above junit test case,
I get below error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: config\export\export.properties (The system cannot find the path specified).
```

I have even tried coping over all the resources from src/main/resources to src/test/resources but it still fails with the same error.
I believe it is something which everyone would be using and must be pretty straighforward...

**EDIT 1**
i created a separate test-context.xml and placed it in the sources and modified it to load files using classpath:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:config/export/export.properties</value>
            </list>
         </property>.
```

after this spring is able to load the properties but on further processing I have below code in logger: `DOMConfigurator.configure("config/export/export_log.xml")` which  fails with `"java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\workspaces\export\job\config/export/export_log.xml".`how does it pick up this path ?

Comment: Use `classpath:`  instead of `file:`.

Comment: I'm surprised it worked using `java -jar`. Solution proposed by @M.Deinum is correct.

Comment: @M.Deinum As my properties are externalized I am using file: in my code.But I tried creating a test-context.xml and placed it in the src/test/resources.Though now it is now able to find config\export\export.properties but on further processing I have below code in logger:          DOMConfigurator.configure("config/export/export_log.xml");this fails with "java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\workspaces\export\job\config/export/export_log.xml".
Why is it looking into the absolute path of the project ?how does it pick up this path

Comment: I wasnt able to format my comment.have added the details in the question

Comment: No it isn't externalized, it is on the class path... Hence you  need to use `classpath:`, the `file:` prefix is for files NOT on the class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by configuring log files as below:

```
DOMConfigurator.configure(JobLogger.class.getClassLoader().getResource("config/export/export_log.xml"))
```